# Gradle in Android Studio 0.44 can't find process on path to run in an Exec Type task

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I used to have the following gradle build task:

```
task buildWebApp(type: Exec) {
    executable = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "grunt.cmd" : "grunt"

    args = ["build"]
}
```

This would pick the appropriate grunt command and run it with the argument "build".

This worked without any kind of issue

I've just tried this in Android Studio 0.4, using Gradle 1.9 and it's no longer working. Instead I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':BrowserPages:buildWebApp'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'grunt''

Normally at this point I would debug with gradlew, but running the following command, throws no errors:

> $ ./gradlew buildWebApp

I've also tried running the full task list to still not find any problems.

The way this is executed is from my main build.gradle file with this dependency

> copyWebApplication.dependsOn ':BrowserPages:buildWebApp'

Anyone have any ideas?

I've tried to run executable = "node" with arg = ["-v"] and get the same error where it can't find node. Node is globally accessible on my terminal, so I can only assume that the command is being run in a different environment to the terminal. There is the option for setting the environment but I can't find any examples of how it should be used.

Comment: Same behaviour in 4.2

Comment: I have the same problem in Android Studio 0.60 when running the following exec: `task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
   commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fully-qualified path to the grunt executable. Perhaps something in the path has changed between Android Studio/Gradle/Android Plugin versions.